# Why my array is sorted even if I didn't do so?

Tags: python

Problem is that after appending values to second array (`arr1`) they somehow sort, and I don't want this.

I searched google as well, but I coulnd't find why it happens

The code:

```
from math import sqrt
def primes(limit):
    tab = []
    for i in range(2, limit):
        for j in tab:
            if i % j == 0: break
        else:
            yield i
            tab.append(i)

def isPrime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % d != 0 for d in range(2, int(sqrt(n))))

arr = []
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
arr3 = list(range(0,1000))
count = 0
count1 = 0
with open("inp.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        arr.append(int(line.rstrip()))
    f.close()
for i in primes(63):
    if isPrime(i):
        for val in arr:
            if val == pow(2,i) - 1:
                arr1.append(val)
for val in arr1:
    print(val)
```

Also inp.txt:

```
3
3
3
7
3
3
3
```

I want to see:

```
3
3
3
7
3
3
3
```

But i get:

```
3
3
3
3
3
3
7
```

Comment: `for i in primes(63):` this is determining the order

Comment: Why the extra `isPrime()` check? Your `primes()` generator produces prime numbers, but you are not sure that it does?

Comment: I dont know why i put it. But still it's not working

Comment: At any rate, your *prime numbers* are sorted, so you'll only find an ordered sequence of `(2 ** prime) - 1` numbers.

Comment: Okey, but how do it properly then? If I do`for i in range(2,63): if isPrime(i): #code` or `for i in primes(63):` result is the same

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework assignment so I will try my best not to give the answer and just help you out. I would throw in a print statement above this for loop to ensure that arr is in the order that you want.  Maybe that will point you in the right direction.

```
  // print arr and check that it is in the correct order //
 for val in arr:
     // if arr is in the correct order check math being pow //
     if val == pow(2,i) - 1:
         arr1.append(val)
 for val in arr1:
     print(val)
```

Comment: The `arr` is correct. I didnt give one `for` loop of `arr` because it's unnecessary to show

Comment: So what's the problem then. I'm bit confused becouse i've issue like this first time